# Jquery, retrieving data from externel url and parsing result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some xml data as result of $ajax call.
The question is, how can i get contents (title) of first  ?

Thank You for help.

[image]

Comment: xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].data;

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
    url: "you url",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      var value = $(xml).find('title').text();  //if only one title node    
    }
});
```

**Explaination**: After getting the response from the url in `xml` you can simply access the `xml` response as a `Jquery object` and use any function of `jquery` on it.

To access Only the first element use `:first` selector on it to access the first title element.

eg: `var value = $(xml).find('title:first').text();`

Comment: I sat that data retrieved from code above dont work on android devices.
I created widget to get data from url and show this on my site, and this works, but when i open site on android, widget is not working....

Comment: I have very less Idea about android devices but as per some posts the problem seems that the ajax requested get cached in the device which creates problem. try to use 'cache:false' propery in the ajax requests. This may help !! :-)

Comment: error:function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
                console.log(textStatus);
                $("#result").html(textStatus);
            }
This code returns "parseerror" - but only on mobile. Desktop works fine, and cache has been disabled.

Comment: Try to serve the document with a 'Content-Type' header of 'application/rss+xml' or 'text/xml' . This may fix the issue

Comment: Great idea, but now this code is not working at all...

"Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

Comment: Are you accessing the file from a local file directory??

Comment: Not able to debug .. Please make another question for it so that it can be reviewed!!! Also please share your code!! :-)